# DataContractSerializer: preserve references

Tags: xml, wcf, serialization

Just a question of curiosity. When i preserve object refernces while serializing an object graph with DataContractSerializer the xml emitted where there are refrences looks like this:

```
<test z:Ref="1" and i:nil="true" />
```

Can anybody tell me why it says i:nil="true" here? Why not just the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the content of the `test` element is empty. `i:nil="true"` is necessary so that the content will validate.

Comment: Thank you very much for picking this up again! I was still wondering :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a reference to your  element.
You must have a definition of your  element previously in the document like this :

```
<test z:Id="1">
    ...
</test>
```

Comment: Yes. But as the questions states: Why the and i:nil="true" - the references element exists.